# Span text scraping inside an IFRAME

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, iframe, webdriver

[1][image: span im trying to scrape]

using imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

I already changed to default and then to orderInfo Iframe :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
def changeIframetoOrders():
    wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait2.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "orderInfo")))
```

I tried by XPath

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/table"
                                                    "/tbody/tr/td/div/span[1]").text)
```

Im always following the rule to change to default iframe and then work on other iframe , still got sometime TimeOut ERROR or cant find element.

My entire code -UPDATED

```
# when i get to this DEF im in moduleManagment iframe
DATELIST = list()
wait5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# that click working in the module iframe
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[" + str(rownumber) + "]/td[7]/div[1]/a").click()
# changing to orders iframe as i listed above
changeIframetoOrders()
# work on this
# print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'activitiy-log-msg')]/span").text)
# trying appending to a list the content of the span ...
DATELIST.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'activitiy-log-msg')]/span").text)
print(DATELIST)
# from here to the end im exit to the module iframe to click some Exit button.
driver.switch_to.default_content()
changeIframetoManagement()

wait5.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal-dialog button.bootbox-close-button"))).click()
return DATELIST
```

ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File , 
line 136, in <module>
changeIframetoOrders()

line 41, in changeIframetoOrders
wait2.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 
"orderInfo")))
 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Can you show all your code, the entire flow and a link to that page?

Comment: link i cant that is a private site , i can show my code

Comment: I ADDED a picture of my code cant add all the code that is like 1000 lines

Comment: Please add a code as a code, not as a picture

Comment: I updated the code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try with `xpath` :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'activitiy-log-msg')]/span
```

**code :**

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'activity-log-msg')]/span").text)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
# when i get to this DEF im in moduleManagment iframe
DATELIST = list()
wait5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# that click working in the module iframe
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[" + str(rownumber) + "]/td[7]/div[1]/a").click()
# changing to orders iframe as i listed above
driver.switch_to.default_content()
changeIframetoOrders()
# work on this
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'activitiy-log-msg')]/span").text)
# trying appending to a list the content of the span ...
```

Comment: unable to locate element i noticed that the activity is writed there as activitiy but still not working

Comment: i did maybe there is a problem with my iframes.. idunno

Comment: I added a picture of my code , your already familliar with my project so i hope you remmember :)

Comment: Can you try to switch to default content first and switch to orderInfo frame and try the above code given by me ?

Comment: I got the issue, check out the updated 1 code, you are missing `driver.switch_to.default_content()` - hopefully this will resolve your issue

Comment: I did it already then the error is timeout

Comment: Now can you share a screenshot I wanna to make sure order info frame shouldn't be in nested iframe

Comment: Or do not use a method, directly try with raw code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234583/discussion-between-ben-cohen-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: well every other element in the order iframe i can reach instead this

Comment: Do you know how to check for unique entry in chrome dev tools ?

Comment: okay, can you go to chrome, (press F12) to open a dev tool, then go to elements section, and do a CTRl  + F and search for `//div[contains(@class, 'activitiy-log-msg')]/span` and see how many entries are there.

Comment: there is two and if i change it to span[1] it is only 1 found

Comment: can you show me which span[1] you are referring to ?

Comment: as you can see in the image above , the one who marked

Comment: nah, that's a absolute xpath, will never work properly

Comment: I need to scrape the date i marked in the image above  the xPath you give me is ok but somehow when im in orderinfo Iframe it can not find this specific div [class = activitiy-log-msg] if i try with the same code to scrape for example a div above im 100% succed thats really strange..

Comment: okay last try, I will say to use explicit wait, just like the wait you have, something like this `print(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath here"))).text)`

Comment: the xpath with span[1]?

Comment: you can with both of them, let's see if anything works

Comment: i succed to scrape only 2 rows and then got an error

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a data-message-id="60e46c8508663" class="btn  btn-sm show-order-info">...</a> is not clickable at point (413, 437). Other element would receive the click: <span data-type="price">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)

Comment: that worked as i can see . in the second try  BRAVO BRAVO im gratfull and keep learning every day ! much thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `ucced to scrape only 2 rows` ? I see you should get only one row

Comment: i run this in for loop for all the rows i got like 5 rows but thats work for now .. best regards.

Comment: I am happy that we could finally solve it. cheers mate !